# Replace the value in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to edit a Pandas dataframe, and you can obtain the dataset from here.
[Sample_dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v-zSCvfNymBADQTuG-rgzpBYaL8QD-HJTX6tgIajns0/edit?usp=sharing)

As you can see, each "area" has some "category" and each "category" has different "price". I want to unify the "category" for each "area", and the value of "category" should be the bottom of each "area". In other words, some values of "category" will change as follows.

Before:
area:A, category:1, price:500

After:
area:A, category:2, price:500

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6NZH.png)

I know that it's possible to edit this dataframe by pivot table as follows. But in this case, I cannot unify and display the values of "category".

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values="price", index=["area",], aggfunc='sum')
```

I would appreciate if you provide an idea to unify the category values.

Comment: Can u supply the data within the image in the question itself, that would make it easier to implement, as far as I can see you are on the right track , what exactly are you missing in the output

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, although it may not be the best option.

After using the code you mentioned:

```py
df_new = pd.pivot_table(df, values="price", index=["area",], aggfunc='sum')
```

I have created a function that finds the last category for each area (where df is the original DataFrame):

```py
    def find_category(cat, list_categories):
        list_categories.append(df[df['area'] == cat].iloc[-1].category)
```

Then with a for loop the last category for each area is searched and added to a new category column. Then you can reorder the columns if you want:

```py
list_categories = [] 

for area in df_new.index:
    find_category(area, list_categories)

df_new['category'] = list_categories
df_new = df_new[['category','price']]
```

The output would be:

```sh
     category   price
area        
A    2          900
B    1          350
C    4          800
D    1          500
```

Comment: Thank for so much! It's a great help.